# Filtering a specific column in a pandas DataFrame using the 'filter' keyword and a lambda function

Tags: dataframe, filter, lambda

How can I use the 'filter' keyword and a lambda function to filter a specific column in a pandas DataFrame?

import pandas as pd
data = [{
'Language': 'Python',
'Percent grow': 56
}, {
'Language': 'Java',
'Percent grow': 34
}, {
'Language': 'C',
'Percent grow': 25
}, {
'Language': 'C++',
'Percent grow': 12
}, {
'Language': 'go',
'Percent grow': 5
}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

f = lambda x : x['Percent grow'] > 30
df.filter(f)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with *[boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)* :

```
df.loc[df["Percent grow"].gt(30)]
```

To make it out with [`pandas.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), one way will be :

```
(
    df
      .set_index("Percent grow")
      .pipe(lambda x: x.filter([x for x in x.index if x>30], axis=0))
      .reset_index()
      .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
)
```

Output :

```
  Language  Percent grow
0   Python            56
1     Java            34
```